# Saving dynamically generated UI (Use Sqlite or not?) in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, android-sqlite

I have an application where the user creates views from predefined XML in runtime. Currently, I'm saving how many views are created by the user in quite. When application restarts the main activity fetches information from SQLite and generate the UI accordingly so that user sees exact UI when leaving application. My question is, is this a good practice to generate UI elements every time user starts the app or is there any other way to save the app state while exiting?

Comment: Does it work flawlessly? Then it's good.

Comment: @Rotwang I have higher end device. On that device it working perfectly. But is it good practice to use database for UI? or is there any other option. So that I can compare the performances of two.

Comment: I think it's fine if you're dynamically creating UI elements

Comment: But is there another way?

Comment: views can only be created "dynamically", there is no other way

Comment: I'm not asking about views I'm asking about saving them. other than SQLite is there another way?

Comment: You **could** use SharedPreferences. But I think that a database is much more an optimized gear to use.

Comment: Thanks, Rotwang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it good practice?

Yes, SQLite is well suited to storing sets of data on a per device basis and is very likely the optimal solution for you.

> is there any other way to save the app state while exiting?

There are a number of ways In addition to using **SQLite**; you could use **Shared Preferences**, save the data to a **file** or use a **server based database** (e.g. Firebase, MySQL etc).

**Shared Preferences** are more suited to saving specific data rather than a varying amount of data (lists or sets of data) . SQLite is better suited to storing varying amounts of data (lists or sets of data).

**Files**. SQLite actually stores the data as a file but it handles the underlying complexities of file management. Writing your own file handling/management would probably have few, if any benefits, at the expense of a lot more work/coding.

**Server based Database**
This has the advantage that the data would be stored elsewhere and could therefore be considered more secure. However, the disadvantage is that the data would have to be remotely accessed thus tying the use of the data to a need for a remote connection. SQLite is client based and inbuilt on Android devices and as such there is no need for remote connectivity.

One potential disadvantage of SQLite is that by default the data will be stored in the App's data. It can thus easily be deleted (via Settings / Apps). You can use external storage for the location of the database. Alternately you could implement backups to external storage (with the ability to restore from the backups).